# TextInput placing an automatic yellow “highlight” behind text react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have a simple TextInput. but When I tap the suggested email, a color highlight appears around my text.
how can i fix this?

here is screenshots

[empty input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyfPt.png)

[input with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYec6.png)

```
<View style={styles.container}>
   {iconName && <Entypo name={iconName} size={20} color={colors.medium} style={styles.icon} />}
    <TextInput
    style={styles.textInput} {...otherProps}  />
</View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        backgroundColor:colors.lightGray,
        borderRadius:25,
        width:'100%',
        padding:15,
        lineHeight:0,
        marginVertical:10,
        flexDirection:"row",
        alignItems:"center"
    },
    icon:{
        marginRight:10,
    },
    textInput:{
        
        fontSize:18,
        color:colors.darkGray,
        width:'90%',
        
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you using `Expo` or `Bare Workflow`?

Comment: I'm using expo and run it in my physical phone

Answer (score 0):

Write now there is not way for `Expo` workflow to remove that background color that appears on selecting suggestions.

But, if you want you can turn off `importantForAutofill` to avoid suggestions.

Like this

```
<TextInput
    placeholder="Enter Email"
    style={{
       borderColor: 'black',
       borderWidth: 1,
       padding: 10,
       backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    }}
    keyboardType="email-address"
    autoCompleteType="email"
    importantForAutofill="no" // this can help a little
/>
```

But if you are on a `Bare Workflow` then [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize#highlighted) can help.

Not Possible in Expo Managed as of now..